# How to change KDE taskbar position?

Tags: kde

I would like to change the position of the KDE taskbar to be at the top of the screen.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on any free space of the taskbar.

Click `Enter Edit Mode`

[image: edit mode]

On the Bar that pops up click and hold at the are which says `Drag to move` and pull the taskbar to the top.

[image: drag]